# Parsing multi nested child in XML in PHP

Tags: php, xml-parsing

Firstly first I am a beginner with PHP. Especially when i have to deal with XML Parsing , I am having a struggle with it right now, lots of xml. Hours and hours already I tried solving it and its already giving me a headache.

Here the XML :

```
<v1:product>
            <v1:data>
                <v1:account_id>5637</v1:account_id>
                <v1:account_name>John Doe</v1:account_name>
                <v1:product_id>f4dc8300-1f13-11e8-bfa43d4d9ee60f6b</v1:product_id>
                <v1:product_name>Product Test</v1:product_name>
                <v1:product_desc>
                    <v1:name>Arc</v1:name>
                    <v1:unit>boxes</v1:unit>
                    <v1:value>10</v1:value>
                </v1:product_desc>
                <v1:product_desc>
                    <v1:name>Birg</v1:name>
                    <v1:unit>kilos</v1:unit>
                    <v1:value>2</v1:value>
                </v1:product_desc>
                <v1:product_desc>
                    <v1:name>Cyitha</v1:name>
                    <v1:unit>Minutes</v1:unit>
                    <v1:value>30</v1:value>
                </v1:product_desc>
                <v1:offer>
                    <v1:offer_id>3575374</v1:offer_id>
                    <v1:offer_name>Flash</v1:offer_name>
                </v1:offer>
            </v1:data>


            <v1:data>
                    <v1:account_id>5892</v1:account_id>
                    <v1:account_name>John Doe</v1:account_name>
                    <v1:product_id>jsad2sdx-asd2-983j</v1:product_id>
                    <v1:product_name>Product Test 2</v1:product_name>
                    <v1:product_desc>
                        <v1:name>Arc</v1:name>
                        <v1:unit>boxes</v1:unit>
                        <v1:value>2</v1:value>
                    </v1:product_desc>
                    <v1:product_desc>
                        <v1:name>Birg</v1:name>
                        <v1:unit>kilos</v1:unit>
                        <v1:value>10</v1:value>
                    </v1:product_desc>
                    <v1:product_desc>
                        <v1:name>Cyitha</v1:name>
                        <v1:unit>Minutes</v1:unit>
                        <v1:value>99</v1:value>
                    </v1:product_desc>
                    <v1:offer>
                        <v1:offer_id>3575374</v1:offer_id>
                        <v1:offer_name>Flash</v1:offer_name>
                    </v1:offer>
             </v1:data>
</v1:product>
```

and this is what i have in PHP

```
$objGetEmAll = new DOMDocument();
$objGetEmAll->loadXML($theXML);
$datas = $objGetEmAll->getElementsByTagName('data');
$responseValue = array();
foreach($datas as $data)        //each element of DATA
{
    $dataValue = array();

    if($data->childNodes->length) 
    {
          foreach($data->childNodes as $i) 
          { 

                $dataValue[$i->nodeName] = $i->nodeValue;
           }
    }

    $responseValue[] = $dataValue;
}
```

but still fail when i want to extract value dynamically inside `product_desc` tag. I want to change XML above into an array which is like below

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [v1:account_id] => 5637
            [v1:account_name] => adsfafds
            [v1:product_id] => 124asd
            [v1:product_name] => HALO
            [v1:product_desc] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [v1:name] => A
                            [v1:unit] => BOXes
                            [v1:value] => 7
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [v1:name] => B
                            [v1:unit] => mins
                            [v1:value] => 1000
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [v1:name] => C
                            [v1:unit] => call
                            [v1:value] => 700
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [v1:name] => D
                            [v1:unit] => GB
                            [v1:value] => 4
                        )

                )

            [v1:offer] => Array
                (
                    [v1:offer_id] => 3575374
                    [v1:offer_name] => Flash
                )

        )

)
```

I know maybe this is the easy one, but for me who just joined programming in these last month, this is confusing. Links or helps are welcome

Comment: `$dataValue[$i->nodeName] = $i->nodeValue;` the `$i->nodeName` will always evaluate to `v1:product_desc` essentially overwriting previous product_desc

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$objGetEmAll = new DOMDocument();
$objGetEmAll->loadXML($theXML);
$datas = $objGetEmAll->getElementsByTagName('data');
$responseValue = array();


foreach($datas as $data)        //each element of DATA
{

    $dataValue = array();
    $product_desc_counter = 0;
    $offer_counter = 0;

    if($data->childNodes->length) 
    {

        foreach($data->childNodes as $i) {

            // for v1:product_desc group case :1
            if($i->nodeName == 'v1:product_desc' ){

                foreach($i->childNodes as $p) { 
                    $dataValue[$i->nodeName][ $product_desc_counter][$p->nodeName] = $p->nodeValue;
                }

                $product_desc_counter ++;
            } else if($i->nodeName == 'v1:offer' ) // for offer group case:2
            {
                foreach($i->childNodes as $p) {
                    $dataValue[$i->nodeName][ $offer_counter][$p->nodeName] = $p->nodeValue;
                }
                $offer_counter ++;
            }
            else // case:3
                $dataValue[$i->nodeName] = $i->nodeValue;
            }

    }

    $responseValue[] = $dataValue;
}
```

In the above lines we loop over all `data` nodes then check if it has any nodes if it doesn't( like for items *account_name*, *product_id* ..) we simply store it's `nodeValue` in our result array ie. in `$responseValue`. If it has any child *(v1:product_desc*,*v1:offer* ie case:1 or 2) we again loop over its children and append them to combination of corresponding key and the corresponding loop counter ( `$product_desc_counter` or `$offer_counter` ) .It might be hard at first to understand (specially array indexes) but after fiddling with it for a while you will grasp it.